# What are these tension-fit electrical connections called?

Tags: connector, components, pins, adapter

Edit: I’m not specifically looking for TRS/audio jack fittings, or this exact shape, I just need angled metal connectors to make a compression fit connection

I’m try to source just the tension-fit metal connectors here to go into a custom adapter, but I don’t know what they’re called so I can’t find them.

What are the pins/connections called?

[image]

Comment: Leaf Spring Contact https://nz.element14.com/keystone/5230tr/leaf-spring-contact-smd-steel/dp/2534544?gclid=CjwKCAjwo_KXBhAaEiwA2RZ8hOO1QfEWsp3Qre71lxp8fKezUOjzFtf5npgNNb01W_-jDV6kkZvU3xoCCzgQAvD_BwE&CMP=KNC-GNZ-SHOPPING-PMAX-2534544

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are these tension-fit electrical connections called? ...
> I don’t know what they’re called so I can’t find them. ...
> What are the pins/connections called?

"spring contacts"

E.g. https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/product-highlight/h/harwin/ez-spring-contacts

Comment: perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Those are 1/4 inch jack-socket contacts.

It is unlikely that you will find those sold separately from an assembled socket.

Comment: I don’t specifically need the TRS socket fitting, I just need a compression fit metal piece that is similar

Answer (score 2):

Compression fit means something else. You're just looking for sockets, like machined pin sockets perhaps. Those come in a range of diameters. Or you may be looking for pogo pins or spring-loaded pins or spring-loaded contacts.